# While reading json data getting null value

Tags: php, mysql, json

Using my php page i m reading mysql data and showing in json. Code of php page is --

```
<?php
    function loadData($limit){
    require "config.inc.php";

    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM UploadText ORDER BY slno DESC LIMIT $limit "); 
    $query->execute();
    $array = array(); 

    while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $id = $data['slno'];
        $title = $data['textmsg']; 

        array_push($array, array(
                "id" => $id,
                "title" => $title
            )
        );
}

echo json_encode($array);
}

function loadMoreData($lastId, $limit){
    require "config.inc.php";
    try{
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM UploadText WHERE slno < $lastId ORDER BY slno DESC LIMIT $limit "); 
        $query->execute();
        $array = array(); 

        while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id = $data['slno'];
            $title = $data['textmsg']; 

            array_push($array, array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "title" => $title
                )
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}



if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "apiText"){
    $lastId = $_GET['lastId'];
    // this is teh limit set in the android java code (LOAD_LIMIT)
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    loadMoreData($lastId, $limit);
} else {
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    loaddata($limit);
}
?>
```

And this is the output of the above code --

```
    [{"id":"14","title":"A Kid On His Way 2 Home With His Mom\r\nSaw A Couple Kissing On The Road,\r\nHe Suddenly Shouted & Said:\r\nLook Mom look, that boy and girl\r\nAre Fighting For A Chewing GUM."},
{"id":"13","title":null},
{"id":"12","title":null},
{"id":"11","title":null},
{"id":"10","title":"PAPPU : Daddy, have you\never been to Egypt?\nFATHER : No. Why do\nyou ask that?\nPAPPU: Well, where did\nyou get THIS mummy??"},
{"id":"9","title":"Y r u so opposite to me?\nWhen i say tea,u say coffee!\nI say white,u say black!\nI went to dental hospital,u went to mental hospital!\nI came back and u still there!"}]
```

Not able to understand, why its reading null values.
Data is present in mysql table, but then also reading some null values and some data are shown properly.

This is the structure of my mysql table --
[image]

Comment: Ex - Heart melting love story:
Boy: I can’t marry u.
My family is totally against it.
Girl: Who r they 2 stop u?
Boy: My wife & 2 kids.

Comment: UTF-8? - no idea

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue by googling, the issue is encoding problem --

```
$title = utf8_encode($data['textmsg']);
```

This resolved the problem.